# Directory Structure for a Small Library

Tags: c#, packaging, directory-structure

So I wrote a fun little extension method library while trying out c# and c# closures(smalltalk style ifTrue,ifFalse and timesRepeat).

I was thinking of putting this on some code sharing site but am unsure of what sort of directory structure it should have(tests,library,license,ect.). Also should I include compiled dlls?

Bonus points if you know of a place that has recommend directory structures for many languages/contexts/frameworks combos.

Answer (score 0):

No need to store compiled DLLs.

For hosting: try [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com) and [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/).

Comment: Roman, take for example this structure: http://code.google.com/p/extsharp/source/browse/ - Browse the trunk folder and see for yourself how this project is organized. "In general", this is the structure of a project that will be available through a SVN repository. People will check out this code (download it to their machines) using a SVN tool as Tortoise http://tortoisesvn.net/. Remember that there's no recipe that fits all projects. So, depending on your project structure you can have more or less folders, etc. Your idea of separating tests, libraries and license stuff is a really good one.